# type error while creating a django model having a file-field

Tags: django, file-upload, filefield, django-models

Getting the following error while trying to create(&save) a django model with file field :

> **TypeError at /admin/app_name/template/add/**
>
> **coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found**

```
 Request Method:     POST 

 Request URL:        http://localhost:8000/admin/app_name/template/add/

 Django Version:     1.4.3
 
 Exception Type:     TypeError
 
 Exception Value:    coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

 Exception Location: path_to_python\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py
                     in force_unicode, line 71
```

here is models.py :-

```
class Template(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True) 
    template = models.FileField(upload_to='templates')

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.title 


class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def upload_file(request,*args, **kwargs):

        if request.method == 'POST':

            instance = Template(template=request.FILES['template'])
            instance.title =request.POST['title']
            instance.save()

admin.site.register(Template, TemplateAdmin)
```

here is settings.py:-

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "media")
```

Also, though there is this error when trying to save(create) a template object, still the file seems to be uploaded in the specified directory (as I can find it in that directory)... However no object instance is created (as `Template.objects.all()` returns an empty list).

Answer (score 0):

solved now...!

the problem was due this silly typing mistake (that I couldn't spot till now)---

```
class Template(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True) 
    template = models.FileField(upload_to='templates')

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.title 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```